# Samsung galaxy A13 airplane mode problem (still emits a few Wifi or BT burst while in sleep mode and pressing the side key from the sleep mode)

Tags: android, galaxy, smartphone, samsung

Checked using an external detector.
I've checked almost everything in the configuration menus. I've also have others samsung phone including an S9 and none emits such RF when I do the similar action.
Phone is up to date was rebooted.
Please is there any expert that knows where the "problem" comes crom and how to solve it please ?
Regards

Checked all the settings I could to disable any emission.